# Testing code dependant on existence of class on classpath

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, classpath

I have a project where I need to provide SLF4J logging if SLF4J is on the classpath and otherwise provide logging straight to the console. I instantiate my logger with code similar to:

```
try {
    Class.forName("org.slf4j.LoggerFactory");
    return new Slf4JLogProvider();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("SLF4J not on classpath, defaulting to console logging");
}
return new ConsoleLogProvider();
```

Note that `Slf4JLogProvider` is a custom wrapper around SLF4J, it's not part of SLF4J itself.

My project is Maven based and this module declares an optional dependency on SLF4J:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

I would like to be able to test this code. Classpath is tricky and properly testing it is IMHO important. Basically, I would like to be able to modify the classloader during my test to ensure SLF4J is absent and validate that console logging is initialized.

Is there any "clean" way of doing this? Any framework that would provide support for classpath dependant tests? Any standard way of isolating test in a specific classloader?

As pointed by @piotrek, this probably makes this an integration test more than a unit test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using a custom classloader. `Class.forName()` calls the classloader which loaded the class containing the Class.forName() call. So, when your class under test tries to load SLF4J, it's going to call the same classloader which loaded the class under test. You could write a custom classloader and use that loader to load a copy of the class under test. That copy of the class would use your custom classloader to load other classes, which gives you an opportunity to hide classes which you don't want the class under test to access.

Your custom classloader would subclass one of the existing classloader classes (ClassLoader or URLClassLoader). You'd add this behavior:

1. When a request is made to load one of the classes, that you want to hide, the loader would pretend the class wasn't found.
2. When a request is made to load the class under test, directly load the class from where it is stored. This gives you a copy of the class which will use this classloader.
3. Requests for other classes (java.lang.String etc) are passed to the parent classloader.

Use this custom classloader to load a copy of the class under test. The resulting class object, and instances created from the class object, would call your custom loader to load other classes. When the class under test tries to load SLF4J, your custom loader would act as if the class didn't exist.

Writing a code example is a little involved, but here are some links that illustrate how to write a custom class loader.

- http://www.journaldev.com/349/java-interview-questions-understanding-and-extending-java-classloader
- http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077260/learn-java/learn-java-the-basics-of-java-class-loaders.html
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-classloader/j-classloader.html

Comment: isn't loaded class cached? he would still have to run tests two times/with two different classpaths, right? or at least prevent loading class during first test

Comment: With the normal classloading mechanism, each classloader holds a reference to the classes which it loads. So classes tend to stay in memory and be reused, yes. But you can create your own classloader outside the normal classloader hierarchy and use it to load classes. If you drop your references to the classloader, the classes loaded from it, and the objects created from those classes, everything becomes subject to garbage collection. And you could create another instance of the loader and do the whole thing again. This is how tomcat etc. handles hot deployment/undeployment of web apps.

Comment: I was hoping someone already wrote some utilities to do just that. The ratio of test code vs functional code does not look goo don this one ;-)

Answer (score -1):

extract `Class.forName("org.slf4j.LoggerFactory");` to separate service and mock it in your tests. you will have one line uncovered

other way is to run some of your tests with different classpaths. unfortunately there is no good support for it in maven or gradle. however with ant/ivy it's easy to do

ps: are you sure you can declare `new Slf4JLogProvider();` in your class if it's not on the classpath? isn't class declaration resolving jvm dependent?

Comment: `Slf4JLogProvider` is a custom class, not part of SLF4J. But I would like my test to catch errors of the same kind. We can discuss if that makes it an integration test more than a unit test ...

Comment: `Class.forName` was already tested by guys that implemented your vm. if you really want to test that call you will have to run your test with 2 different classpaths

Comment: The problem is not testing that `Class.forName()` works. The problem is testing that if the class I use as marker is not present, I can load my fallback class correctly and I do not have some hidden dependency on something I did not expect.

Comment: if that line is in another service then mock that service and make mock throw same exception that Class.forName throws. then you will test your fallback code

Comment: That would be a unit test. What is required here is an integration or system test. The problem is not that `Class.forName()` will throw an exception, or have special behaviour in special cases. The goal is to validate that the rest of the code works properly as well. For example, say that my `ConsoleLogProvider` depends on `org.slf4j.Marker`, mocking `Class.forName()` to throw a `ClassNotFoundException` will work, `ConsoleLogProvider` will be loaded, test will be green. But in fact, implementation is broken, because I have a hidden dependency on SLF4J.